# Strategy to keep ViewModel and persistence in sync in C# WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, treeview

I try to keep a TreeView in sync with my data layer during drag-drop operations.

**Questions**

1. Should operations in the TreeView like drag-and-drop act on the ItemViewModel or should these be send to the service/data layer and then update the ItemViewModel?
2. I currently have two Tree structures, one in my data layer and one in my view layer. With regard to question 1 is this the proper way to do this?

**Background**

I have a model that contains a nested structure. This model is accessible through a service.

Data layer:

```
public class ItemBase 
{
    public string Name;
    public ItemBase Parent;
    public List<ItemBase> Children;
}

public class Building : ItemBase{}
public class Floor: ItemBase{}
public class Room: ItemBase{}
public class Device: ItemBase{}

public interface ITopologyService 
{
    public ICollection<ItemBase> getTopologyRoot();
    public ICollection<ItemBase> getChildren(ItemBase item);
    public AddItem(ItemBase item);
    public RemoveItem(ItemBase item);
    public void MoveItem(ItemBase item, ItemBase target);
    public void SaveTopology(ICollection<ItemBase> topology);
}
```

My view model structure is based on https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26288/Simplifying-the-WPF-TreeView-by-Using-the-ViewMode

View layer:

```
public class TopologyTreeViewModel : ViewModelBase 
{
    private readonly ITopologyService _topologyService;
    private readonly ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> _itemViewModels;

    public IEnumerable<ItemViewModel> ItemViewModels => _itemViewModels;

    public TopologyTreeViewModel(ITopologyService service)
    {
        this._topologyService = service;
        Load();
    };

    public void Load()
    {
        ICollection<ItemBase>items = _topologyService.GetRootItems();

       _itemViewModels.Clear();

        foreach (ItemBase item in items)
        {
            _itemViewModels.Add(ItemViewModelFactory.GetViewModelByModel(item, _topologyService));
        }
    }

    public void Drop(ItemViewModel item, ItemViewModel target)
    {
        _topologyService.MoveItem(item, target);

        // Question here: Should this be something like this?
        item.Parent = target;
        target.Children.Add(item);
        // Or should this reload the entire model?
    }  
}
```

Wrapper around my models to add TreeView specific functions.

```
public class ItemViewModel
{
    readonly ItemViewModel Parent;
    readonly ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> Children;
    readonly ItemBase Item;
    readonly ITopologyService _topologyService;
    static readonly ItemViewModel DummyChild = new ItemViewModel();

    public bool IsSelected;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _item.Name; }
    }

    protected ItemViewModel(ITopologyService service, ItemViewModel parent, ItemViewModel item)
    {
        _topologyService = service;
        Parent = parent;
        Item = item;
        Children = new ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel>();
        Children.Add(DummyChild);
    }

    //Lazy Load on expanding.
    private bool _isExpanded;
    public bool IsExpanded 
    {
        get { return _isExpanded; }
        set {
            if (_isExpanded && _parent != null)
                _parent.IsExpanded = true;
            if (this.HasDummyChild)
            {
                this.Children.Remove(DummyChild);
                this.LoadChildren();
            }
        }
  
    protected void LoadChildren()
    {
        ICollection<ItemBase>items = _topologyService.GetChildren(this.item);
        this.Children.Clear();
        foreach (ItemBase item in items)
        {
            this.Children.Add(ItemViewModelFactory.GetViewModelByModel(item, _topologyService));
        }
    }
}
```

```
public class BuildingItemViewModel : ItemViewModel{}
public class FloorItemViewModel : ItemViewModel{}
public class RoomItemViewModel : ItemViewModel{}
```

In my `TopologyTreeView.xaml`:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding ItemViewModels}">>
<TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ItemViewModel}">
        <EventSetter Event="MouseMove" Handler="Item_MouseMove" />
        <EventSetter Event="DragOver" Handler="Item_DragOver" />
        <EventSetter Event="Drop" Handler="Item_Drop" />
        <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
<TreeView.Resources>
<HierarchicalDataTemplate 
    DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:BuildingItemViewModel}" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image Width="16" Height="16" Margin="3,0" Source="/Icons/Toolbar/Building.png" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
<HierarchicalDataTemplate 
    DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:FloorItemViewModel}" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image Width="16" Height="16" Margin="3,0" Source="/Icons/Toolbar/Floor.png" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
..
</TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
..
```

This code is a snippet and is not complete but tries to convey my question.

Comment: If you can drag unexpanded items, I would think there might be no viewmodel children. I'm not so sure about lazy loading btw. Creating viewmodels is usually very quick, it's UI takes time and you don't have any UI children if your tree item is not expanded.

Answer (score 0):

> Should operations in the TreeView like drag-and-drop act on the ItemViewModel or should these be [sent] to the service/data layer and then update the ItemViewModel?

Your source of truth needs to be updated first. If the view after a drop is **not consistent** with the source of truth, then the view needs to be refreshed by getting the truth and re-loading the tree.

If the load of the call does not affect processing, re-loading the data *after* the source of truth is updated is not a bad idea. Such updating is done all the time by removing a reference to a list only to provide a new list's reference causing an update to the screen.

> I currently have two Tree structures, one in my data layer and one in my view layer. With regard to question 1 is this the proper way to do this?

The proper way is the way that works with trade offs being ease of coding vs speed of the view (GUI) while that operation is being undertaken. That decision is yours.

Comment: Thank you! Question: In the Drop function the truth can be updated through the service, but how does this update flow back to the `ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel>Children` in the tree root or the ItemViewModel? I suppose calling LoadChildren on the old and the new ViewModel but I do not see how to call the right one.